# How can I universally disable titles on hover in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

How can I prevent tooltips from appearing when I hover elements with the title attribute, in Safari 14 on macOS Big Sur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the delay for all Safari tooltips by setting `NSInitialToolTipDelay`. If you set a really long time, it's like they're disabled. For example, 10 seconds:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 10000
```

Delete to use the default value

```
defaults delete com.apple.Safari NSInitialToolTipDelay
```

---

Safari stores preferences in its sandbox container and `defaults` will only look in the container if you don't have a preferences file from a time when Safari wasn't sandboxed (e.g. if you've upgraded macOS and kept your home directory). Check you don't have a `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` file for `defaults` to use the one at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`, or manually provide this domain to `defaults`:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 10000
```